# Print as PDF of a page using RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping, rselenium

I'm trying to collect data by saving the objects as PDF's using Selenium in R. I'm having some issues when reaching to the print-dialog window. My strategy has been to try to skip the print prompt/dialog but I can't get it to work. I tried this:

```
cprof <- list(
  chromeOptions = 
    list(prefs = list(
      'profile.default_content_settings.popups' = 0L,
      'download.prompt_for_download' = FALSE,
      'download.default_directory' = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Text',
      'download.directory_upgrade' = TRUE,
      'plugins.plugins_disabled" = 'Chrome PDF Viewer',
      'print.prompt' = FALSE
      )
    )
  )
```

But the print dialog/prompt is still there. I know one way is to make the browser to be in kiosk-mode but I haven't found a way to do this in R (there are several threads about how to do it in Java or Python).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I needed to figure this out, as well. Based on [these docs](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities) (see the "args" entry in the "Recognized capabilities" section, which references [these additional docs](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)), the following worked for me:

```
eCaps <- list(
    chromeOptions = 
        list(args = list('--kiosk-printing')))

remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, 
                      browserName = "chrome", extraCapabilities = eCaps)
```

Then, once you open a window with the PDF you want to save, the following automatically saves it to your specified download directory without any additional prompts:

```
remDr$findElements('css selector', 'html')[[1]]$sendKeysToElement(list(key='control', 'p'))
```